# Python error: Big-endian buffer not supported on little-endian compiler

Tags: python, pandas, endianness

When i run my python code (a very simple piece of code that was previously tested and no such error occured), i got this error:

ValueError: Big-endian buffer not supported on little-endian compiler

My Code (partial):

```
key = '|'.join(dealList)

print key  #key is the column name i'm searching for
try:

    #use REGEX since dealID is not exactly the same as the col name
    dealVector0 = self.crm_var0.filter(regex=key)
    dealVector1 = self.crm_var1.filter(regex=key)
    ...
```

self.crm_var1 is a pandas dataframe

Comment: Sounds like you've not installed the correct version of `pandas` for your machine. Do other panda functions work?

Comment: @danodonovan Yes, they work

Comment: Please show the full stack trace